# Adding columns gives error Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

This is odd, this code worked yesterday to add columns today it errors. Below is all there is of the code.

```vb
Option Explicit 

'Workbook, worksheets setting 

Public WbName As Workbook 
Public WsName1 As Worksheet, WsName2 As Worksheet, WsName3 As Worksheet, WsName4 As Worksheet 

Const SPSITE = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/teams/xxxxxxTeam" 
Const SRCLIST = "{57FDE37F-5EBD-ZZZZ-XXXX-EBE432345E2B}" 

Public Src(0 To 1) As Variant 
Dim MyTableName As String 
Public ObjListTable As ListObject 
Public LastRowEquip As Long 
Public LastColEquip As Long 
Dim Wrk As String, TableTxt As String 

Sub Headache() 

Set WbName = ThisWorkbook 

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate 

Set WsName3 = WbName.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set WsName4 = WbName.Sheets("Sheet4") 

'Delete all off sheet
WsName4.Cells.Delete 

'download Table 
Src(0) = "https://" & SPSITE & "/_vti_bin" 
Src(1) = SRCLIST 
WsName4.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, Src, True, xlYes, WsName4.Range("A1") 

'Once table is open
Set ObjListTable = WsName4.ListObjects(1) 

'Done this way to prove List objects could be read 
LastRowEquip = ObjListTable.ListRows.Count 
LastColEquip = ObjListTable.ListColumns.Count 
TableTxt = ObjListTable.Name 

MsgBox TableTxt & " Last row " & LastRowEquip & " Last column " & LastColEquip  'just proof

'add columns
ObjListTable.ListColumns.Add(LastColEquip + 1).Range.Resize(, 2).Insert  '******* guilty line *******' 

'copy in data
WsName4.Range("P1:S" & LastRowEquip).Value = WsName3.Range("A1:D" & LastRowEquip).Value '**** Temporary till Sharepoint updated 

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? On which line do you get an error? What has changed since yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

The line that causes the error is the one that says "guilty".
I am suspected it got disconnected from Sharepoint. I found that if I hit the unlink button then the code will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).